# Java UML Reverse Engineering Tool for component view

Tags: gratis, java, uml, component-diagram, reverse-engineering

After reading [this post](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1878/217) I found another problem.

I am looking for a free reverse engineering tool that can analyse a multi-modules Java project and create an editable UML file but not the class diagram which will be too huge but a more syntetic view like the Component Diagram which can shows the dependencies between all modules.

My Java modules are of these different types: 
 - EJB
 - JAR
 - WAR
 - EAR (global application)

We have already the maven plugin [Maven-Graph-Plugin](http://mvnplugins.fusesource.org/maven/1.4/maven-graph-plugin/reactor-mojo.html) but it makes only a graphic (PNG) which is not editable.

I am looking for something similar but in a UML software; a plugin for Eclipse (or another program) would make me happy as well.