# Generate UML diagrams from Java code

Tags: gratis, java, eclipse, uml

Does someone know a good free application/plugin for Eclipse to transform the Java code into UML diagrams and vice versa?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Software to generate class diagram from Java source, not dependent on Eclipse](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/software-to-generate-class-diagram-from-java-source-not-dependent-on-eclipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse itself has a plug-in called **[Papyrus](https://eclipse.org/papyrus/)**.

> Papyrus is a UML tool that provide very advanced facilities for customizing the tool.

This plug-in supports both generating a UML diagram to Java source code and reversing Java source code to a UML diagram (reverse engineering). There is a well written documentation for end user to do those. Please, take a look the following links:

- [Java code generation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Java_Code_Generation)
- [Java reverse engineering](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Java_reverse_engineering)

I don't know what a "good" application/plug-in means. But, since you said a plug-in for Eclipse, I hope this one will satisfy your needs.

Comment: Thank you for you're answer, I will take a look on the plugin and I will come back with a post.

Comment: Is working fine for what I want, but now I still need to know how to use Papyrus to generate UML from code. But thx for help

Answer (score 0):

Papyrus website itself provides very limited information on how to use it. I would recommend to install Eclipse, go to help, install new software -> Marc repo -> modelling -> Papyrus UML.

As for how to use it check UML Tutorial 3.0 - Basics of Java Class Diagrams in Eclipse with Papyrus (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pim22rLtsW0).

Install, restart Eclipse, go to help -> install new software -> add
http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/updates/releases/mars

Remove group by category. Install:
Papyrus Java classes generator
Papyrus Java reverse (incubation)
Papyrus Profile for Java modules (Incubation)

Accept security, restart Eclipse.

Help-> Eclipse marketplace -> search for "QVT", install QVT operational.

As for how to use it check UML Tutorial 3.0 - [Basics of Java Class Diagrams in Eclipse with Papyrus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pim22rLtsW0).